# How to test whether all values exist in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have clients table, projects table and issues table.

```
clients
cid  cname
-----------
 c1   ca  
 c2   cb
 c3   cc

projects
pid  pname  cid
----------------
 p1   pa     c1
 p2   pb     c1
 p3   pc     c1
 p4   pd     c2
 p5   pe     c2

issues 
iid  iname  pid
----------------
i1     ia   p1
i2     ib   p2
i3     ic   p4
i4     id   p5
```

I want clients whose projects are all exist in issues. It is c2.
How to write MYSQL query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `having` clause:

```
select
    c.cid,
    c.cname
from clients c
left join projects p
on c.cid = p.cid
left join issues i
on p.pid = i.pid
group by c.cid, c.cname
having count(distinct p.pid) = count(distinct i.pid) and count(distinct p.pid) > 0
```

Check [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b71e77/1) Demo Here.

Comment: This worked fine for me. Best answer. Thanks @Forward.

Answer (score 2):

The following query should give you the list of client IDs that have all projects listed in the issue table:

```
SELECT p.cid
FROM projects AS p LEFT JOIN issues AS i ON p.pid=i.pid
GROUP BY p.cid
HAVING COUNT(*)=SUM(CASE WHEN i.iid is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
```

I use a `LEFT JOIN` such that I get all rows of `projects`, and if a `pid` does not exist in `issues` the values for issues (such as `i.iid`) will be `NULL`.

*Note*: I have updated using the SQL fiddle of Forward.